# Javascript variables in class methods are not persisting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am generating inputs on a form in a React class. The inputs will write to a deeply nested JSON object. As I generate each input, I pass the series of keys as an array to help the input determine where it should be writing within the JSON object.

example ['option1', 'option2', option3]

```
{ 
  option1: {
   option2: {
     option3: {}
   }
}
```

Here is the actual class method I am using:

```
 generateNode(fields, path) {
   return (
    <NodeSection>
      {Object.keys(fields).map(key => {
        return this.generateInput(fields[key], path)
      })}
    </NodeSection>
  );
}
```

Now, inside generateInput I return an input with the path set in in onChange method:

```
generateInput(input, path) { 
  return (
    <div>     
      <input value={this.getValue(input.name, path)} 
        onChange={e => { 
           this.setValue(e.target.value, input.name, path)
       }} />
     </div>
  );
}
```

So, the issue is that I want to have an input that will set a value in each level of the path. So to the first input I pass as path:

```
 ['option1']
```

The second input I pass this as path:

```
  ['option1', 'option2']
```

And to the final input, I pass this as path:

```
 ['option1', 'option2', 'option3']
```

But when I try to alter data on the first input (['option1']), it passes

```
  ['option1', 'option2', 'option3']
```

???

I can see that when I generated the input via the parent method, I passed ['option1']. But that value seems to get overridden by the next two method calls/input generations. setValue passes the 3-item array every time on all three inputs. Which results in the inner-most JSON object level being written to, always.

I'm pretty stuck. Any ideas?

Here is set value, if it helps. I can tell you, at this point "path" is already the three-item array. From logs I can see it gets changed between the very top generateNode (I've previously had the path printed inside the node permanently) and generateNode. By the time it hits generateNode, the array which was passed is no longer the array in the function. I suspect due to subsequent calls.

```
setValue(value, name, path) {
  const tree = this.state.treeLoadedForEditing;
  const node = this.getNodeByPath(path);
  if (node) {
    node[name] = value;
  }
  this.setState({ treeLoadedForEditing: tree });
}
```

This is the method that calls generateNode:

```
generateNodeSections() {
const { treeLoadedForEditing, pathInView } = this.state; 
if (treeLoadedForEditing.title) {
  const nodeSections = [];
  let currentPath = [];
  let pathIdx = 0;  
  let currentTreeLevel = treeLoadedForEditing; 
  while(currentTreeLevel.node) {
    const nodeData = this.getFieldDataFromRawNode(currentTreeLevel.node);
    // generates the node at the given path
    const node = this.generateNode(nodeData, currentPath); 
    nodeSections.push(node);
    currentPath.push(pathInView[pathIdx]); 
    if (currentTreeLevel.children && Object.keys(currentTreeLevel.children).length) {
      currentTreeLevel = currentTreeLevel.children[currentPath[currentPath.length - 1]]
    } else {
      // this stops the loops
      currentTreeLevel = {}; 
    }
    pathIdx++;
  }
  return nodeSections; 
}
```

}

Comment: It sounds like you're just appending a value to the same array each time, can you show us your `setValue` and `getValue` methods?

Comment: What calls `generateNode`?

Comment: I've added it. Although I can tell you, by the time it hits setValue, the path has been changed.

Comment: I've added the method that calls generateNode as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By the time it hits generateNode, the array which was passed is no longer the array in the function.

Actually, exactly the opposite is true. The array is *always* the same array as in the function. Arrays do not pass by value, they pass by *reference*, and that means the `path` that gets carried all the way down to your `setValue` is a reference to exactly the same array that's being modified by your `generateNodeSections` here:

```
currentPath.push(pathInView[pathIdx]);
```

Every time a value is pushed to `currentPath`, it modifies that array which is being used by every single `generateNode` and thus every `generateInput` and `onChange`. You should hand off a copy of the array instead of a reference to the original, like this:

```
const node = this.generateNode(nodeData, [...currentPath]);
```

`[...currentPath]` is a short way to create a shallow copy of the array. That way you'll be passing an unchanging snapshot of what the path was at the time that you called the function.

Comment: I am so happy with you! Thank you!

Comment: Been banging my head on this all day